How to change my Console app .NET Framework in VS Comunnity 2019 while creating a project to just Console app?
When i run VS Community 2019 while creating a project and searching for Console App with C# it only shows me 1 option (Console.app .NET Framework), how can i create a project with just Console App without the .NET Framework?...
I have marked in the modify installer:
-ASP.NET and Web Development
-.NET Dekstop Development
-.NET cross-platform development(out of support)

You can't and it wouldn't make sense. A console app runs either on .NET Framework or the newer .NET (formerly .NET Core), which I'm not sure whether is supported in VS 2019. What precisely do you want to achieve when you want to create a Console app "without .NET Framework"?

I am a student and our lector told us to use Console.App without .NET Framework but my version has it only with .NET Framewrok , i cannot download other version becouse my system is x32Bit..

The template of the Console App for the new .NET versions is only called "Console App", which probably refers to your instruction "without .NET Framework" (I have both in VS 2022). If you can't install VS2022, you should probably talk to your lector for an alternative.

Yep that's what i'm gonna do, thanks for the help!
